# Pandas Aggregated df showing differing number of columns between head() and .info() due to MultiIndexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm aggregating my df:

```
dfAvg_Volume_RFQ = dfSpecific_Client_Avg_Volume_RFQ.groupby(['Client', 'currency', 'sales_person_name2']).agg({'state': 'size', 'Quantity': 'mean', 'Quantity_CAD': 'mean'})

print(dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.info())

MultiIndex: 1127 entries, (A......) to (Z.....)
    Data columns (total 3 columns):
    state           1127 non-null int64
    Quantity        1127 non-null float64
    Quantity_CAD    1127 non-null float64
```

When I then view the df's head its showing all six columns. When I run other aggregations on `dfSpecific_Client_Avg_Volume_RFQ` it's only using the three columns in info which is a problem.

```
print(dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.head(5))

                                       state      Quantity  \
Client  currency sales_person_name2                           
A       USD      OSCAR                  2         2050000.0000   
AA      USD      NAZ                    10        11500000.0000   
AAR     USD      JOSHUA                 1         15000.0000   
ABC     USD      ANGELA                 1         5000000.0000   
                 HANS                   1         10000000.0000   

                                                  Quantity_CAD  
Client  currency sales_person_name2                           
A       USD      OSCAR                  2         2050000.0000   
AA      USD      NAZ                    10        11500000.0000   
AAR     USD      JOSHUA                 1         15000.0000   
ABC     USD      ANGELA                 1         5000000.0000   
                 HANS                   1         10000000.0000   

print(dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.columns)

   state       Quantity   Quantity_CAD
0      1  50000000.0000  47523999.6198
1      4 300000000.0000 399625821.9816
2     18 274241666.6667 365848851.3870
3      1 300000000.0000 409165302.7823
4     32 138905156.2500 138905156.2500

print (dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.index.names)

Index(['state', 'Quantity', 'Quantity_CAD'], dtype='object')
['Client', 'currency', 'sales_person_name2']
```

When grouping and summing on numerous columns is it not possible to produce a df without the multiindex in the first place?

Comment: Is possible add small data sample to question for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @jezrael. This df is very large so can't paste. It also has client information,. but I have updated the .head output

Comment: Issue appears to be with the construction of the initial aggregation producing the multiindex

Comment: hmmm, what about `print (dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.columns)`? There are not 3 columns and 3 levels of MultiIndex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is expected, because there is not 6 columns, but 3 level MultiIndex and 3 columns.

Test it by:

```
print (dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.columns)

print (dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.index.names)
```

If need convert `MultiIndex` to columns use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or parameter `as_index=False` in `groupby`:

```
dfAvg_Volume_RFQ = dfAvg_Volume_RFQ.reset_index()
```

Or:

```
dfAvg_Volume_RFQ = dfSpecific_Client_Avg_Volume_RFQ.groupby(['Client', 'currency', 'sales_person_name2'], as_index=False)
                                                   .agg({'state': 'size', 'Quantity': 'mean', 'Quantity_CAD': 'mean'}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an aggregation on a groupby, the column(s) used in the groupby constitute the index of the result DataFrame. So in your example, 'Client', 'currency', 'sales_person_name2' constitute the index and you only have 3 *true* columns: `state`, `Quantity` and `Quantity_CAD`.

If you want to get rid of indexing and have 6 columns, just use `reset_index`:

```
dfAvg_Volume_RFQ = dfSpecific_Client_Avg_Volume_RFQ.groupby(
    ['Client', 'currency', 'sales_person_name2']).agg({'state': 'size',
                                                       'Quantity': 'mean',
                                                       'Quantity_CAD': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

You will get a DataFrame with a simple RangeIndex and 6 data columns